# IntelliJ - push simultaneously to 2 Git repo's

Tags: git, intellij-idea

How can I easily push changes simultaneously to 2 git repo's using IntelliJ?

**I see quite OLD answers. Are there nowadays better solutions?**

I know that I can add 2 remotes so that via the terminal I can push to 2 reps via 1 command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for some new feature in IntelliJ that allows pushing to two remotes from one repo simultaneously via the UI, there is no such, and there are no plans to add it at the moment.

The solution is still the same - add 2 remotes in git config to tell git client push to two remotes.